# WPF ListView Selection with RadioButton in ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, styles, mvvm-light

I use MVVM Light (WPF). 
I want to build a menu of checkboxes styled as ToggleButtons in a ListView and show some controls in a contentcontrol depending on which checkbox is being checked. The ItemSource of the ListView I have set to an `ObservableCollection<ViewModelInfo>` where the `ViewModelInfo` objects holds information about the ViewModel and View to show. The listview's `SelectedItem` I have bound to a `SelectedViewModelInfoItem` property on the ViewModel. The `SelectedViewModelInfoItem` property will grab the information from the selected `ViewModelInfo` item and set the correct content control.

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding LeftPaneViewModelInfoItems}" 
          Background="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewModelInfoItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Text}" 
                         Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonToggleButtonStyle}" 
                         GroupName="DisplayPage"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The problem I see is that the selection of the ListView seems completely separate from the RadioButtons checked state, so I have to click next to the toggle button to select it also I get an overlay color from the ListView.

**Question:** How do I easiest show my collection of `ViewModeInfo` as a list of togglebuttons making sure I only see a list of togglebuttons (not the highlight overlay from the ListView) still making sure the selected (checked togglebutton) is set as the `SelectedViewModelInfoItem`.

I should mention I have explored the `EventToCommand`, binding the Radiobutton's Checked event to a RelayCommand on the ViewModel. It would work if I could just get the actual ViewModelItem as an event argument instead of the default EventArgs (which source is the radiobutton). I was not able to solve it that way, but if there is a way to get the ViewModelItem as the eventarg it could be a nice solution.

Comment: You may use an ItemsControl (which does not provide selection) and bind the RadioButton's IsChecked property to your view model item.

Comment: But how can I then get which ViewModelInfo that is checked?

Comment: Each ViewModelInfo would have a boolean property that you would bind to. As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource binding is pointless. It has no effect in a OneWay Binding like this.

Comment: @Clemens I guess, @Johan doesn't have any `bool` property with his model to represent the Selection. I see that, he is relying on the `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` to get the checked item.

Comment: @Clemens, Yeah, definitely. It's one more way of getting the selected item. Personally, i see it'll be more helpful when multiple selection is needed.

Comment: @Clemens
Just out of curiosity, if I add a Selected boolean in my ViewModelInfo class, bind Radiobutton's IsChecked to it, switch to an ItemsControl. 
How should I trigger the code to run on the ViewModel, setting the content control? Would you normally hook up to the click event of the ItemsControl (using EventToCommand to make it run a RelayCommand Action on the ViewModel)...or is there a better way?

I agree Clemen's answer would be the better one if one need to support multi-selection.

Comment: The main view model could attach a PropertyChanged event handler to each ViewModelInfo object to get notified about its changes, and manage an own SelectedItem or SelectedItems property. But since this is plain *selection* you should just use an ItemControl that supports it, i.e. a ListBox.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can bind the `IsSelected` property of the `ListViewItem` to `IsChecked` property of `RadioButton` to achieve this. Like,

```
<ListView  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding LeftPaneViewModelInfoItems}" 
           Background="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewModelInfoItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Text}" 
                         Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonToggleButtonStyle}" 
                         GroupName="DisplayPage"
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If you want to completely remove the Selection background colouring completely, you can use below `ItemContainerStyle` along with above change.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks this did exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but the style for the checkbox is not working completely. Since I don't know if it is related I posted a separate question about it here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858349/wpf-style-basedon-does-not-work