# WPF Style BasedOn does not work

Tags: wpf, styles, basedon

I have made a style RadioButtonToggleButtonStyle as below.

```
  <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                        d1p1:Ignorable="d" 
                        xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"                    
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TeachpendantControl">

        <Style x:Key="RadioButtonToggleButtonStyle" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
               TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>   
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

I use it like this below.

```
 <ListBox  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" ItemsSource="{Binding LeftPaneViewModelInfoItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewModelInfoItem}">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton 
                                Content="{Binding Text}"                                     
                                GroupName="DisplayPage"
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                                Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonToggleButtonStyle}"                                     
                                >                                    
                            </RadioButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

The `CheckBoxes` show up as `ToggleButtons` when I run the application (but it shows up as `CheckBoxes` in Design mode).

But I don't get a gold background when the `CheckBox` (styled as `ToggleButton`) is checked. Also Visual Studio (2015) complains in the resource file saying **"The resource {x:Type ToggleButton}"** could not be resolved.

Can anyone provide an explanation of why this does not work (and how to solve it)

Comment: Thanks that was a typo, I should not bind to the style. Changing it helped to see toggle buttons in Design mode now and removed the error message. 

Still the problem remains, the Background is not changed on IsChecked.

Comment: Yes I have removed the typo

Comment: In the Checked state, the default ToggleButton Template doesn't show any element the uses the Background property. You would have to modify the ToggleButton Template.

Comment: Thanks yes, the style below with  a ToggleButton template solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `ControlTemplate` to be able to change the `Background` of a `ToggleButton`.

The default `ControlTemplate` contains hardcoded values that take precedence over the value that you specify in your `Style`.

You can copy the default template into your project by right-clicking on a `ToggleButton` in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy and then edit it as per your requirements. Try this:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Gold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: And thanks for the extra information of Edit->Copy in Visual Studio, I only thought one could do that in Blend.